# vb.net how to set different post build events per platform

Tags: vb.net, build

Setting the post-build event in vb.net is seems to always be set for all configurations and all platforms - even though I want it to vary in each case.  Is there a way to enforce the latter behaviour?

Currently I am forced to test `IF "$(PlatformName)"=="x64"`, and so on, in the post-build event command line - ugly!

I have *not* got `All Configurations` selected fwiw.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a bunch of `cmd` files named `postbuild_x64.cmd`, `postbuild_x86.cmd` and then invoke them using `call postbuild_$(PlatformName).cmd`.

Comment: Fair, I could do that.  But isn't VS supposed to support this behaviour out of the box, like it would for C++ projects?